# How to show pagination for limiter of 5?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have huge results and paginated according to the results.

```
$total_records = 156;
$limit = 20;
$total = ceil($total_records/$limit);
<previous>
for($i=1;$i<$total;$i++){
$paging .= <li>$i</li>;
}
<next>
```

outputs

```
1 2 3 ... 32 pages.
```

How to control the pagiantion handling if the user select 5 per limit and show
the pages

1 2 3 5 6 7 8 next
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 next
15 16 32 next

Comment: what is `<previous>` and `<previous>` in your code?

Comment: Previous is link for after 2 pages